# UIImageView frame not placing correctly on the parent ImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiimageview, coordinates

I have a color palette imageview, in that I want to place a plus icon(imageView) according to the x and y-axis I am getting from the backend. If I get x = 0 and y = 0 the frame of the plus is placing correctly

[image: x=0,y=0]

For y axis if I set height of the color palette imageView to the plus icon's frame's y axis, the icon is not going to the actual (0,0)

[image: x=0,y=width].

The code I used is below

```
 let cWidth = self.colorPalleteImageView.frame.size.width // 348
 let cHeight = self.colorPalleteImageView.frame.size.height // 378.5

 let imageView = UIImageView(image: appImages.roundPlusIcon.image)
 imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: cHeight, width: 22, height: 22)
 colorPalleteImageView.addSubview(imageView)
```

I am checking this with iPad 12.9 inch simulator. Am I missing anything to achieve that x=0 and y=0, If I give the width of the colorPaletteImage to the x-axis of plusIconImageView it is not going to end fo the x-axis, It stays before the end of the width of the imageview, I don't know why it is happening, Need help

Comment: First, why aren't you using auto-layout and constraints? Second, when are you doing this? If this code is in `viewDidLoad()`, for example, the frames are not finished being set.

Comment: @DonMag I thought it is not possible to move the frame dynamically if I use the plus icon with auto-layout, that's why created it programmatically. I am doing this in viewWillAppear().

Comment: Layout is not finished in `viewWillAppear()`, which is likely your problem. Is your color-palette imageView a fixed size? Or does it change based on device? Show the code you are using to set the frame of your imageView.

Comment: Yes, you are right, that's the problem. color-palette imageView will change based on the device, now I tried in viewDidLayoutSubviews, it called twice and created two plus icon's, second one's frame set perfectly, If I set the frame of my imageView in viewDidAppear will solve my issue?

Comment: I added this as an answer, so other folks who come across this question will see the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using frame sizes *before* the frames are finished being set by auto-layout.

I'd suggest using constraints, but if you want to stick to frame coordinates...

- add the "round plus" icon imageView in `viewDidLoad()`
- set its `frame.origin` in `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` or `viewDidAppear()`

Answer (score 0):

imageView.frame = CGRect(x: cWidth, y: cHeight, width: 22, height: 22)

mast be:

imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 22, height: 22)

as axes are:

0,0-----------------> x

| ▢

|

|

|

V

with 0,0 you put top left of little image to to top left of big.

Comment: Yes, If I give (0,0) then its working fine. If I give (x=0, y=cHeight), then the small icon should be in the bottom left, but it is not going to the bottom left, that's the issue

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this issue by modifying the `height` property to the super view's bound's height. You need to know the difference between `frame` and `bounds` to understand why this is happening. In simple words frame is the CGRect with respect to it's super view and bounds is the `CGRect` with respect to it's own coordinates. 
Plenty of detailed explanations are available online just need to google frame vs bounds and you'll get used to both of these after you play with it many times.
Here's how you fix this issue.

```
let cHeight = self.colorPalleteImageView.bounds.size.height
```

Comment: I tried this earlier and after seeing your answer also I tried it, but it is not coming to the bottom left, it is coming like the second image (in question) only

Comment: Can you try modifiying the addSubview this: `colorPalleteImageView.addSubview(imageView)` to this: `colorPalleteImageView.superview?.addSubview(imageView)`

Comment: sure, let me try

Comment: Its going outside of the colorPalleteImageView (i.e its superview) and the plusIcon did not come to the bottom left, remains the same position as the second image (in question) only

Comment: I don't understand. Are you doing something else here? Maybe the entire context is not provided in the question or you are not doing exactly as I have told you. Just try giving the frame.size.height in cHeight and add the imageView as I've told for checking.

Answer (score 0):

sorry.. I am back

I did (to follow your code I forced values..)

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var colorPalleteImageView: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let v = self.view
        print(v!.frame)

        let cHeight = CGFloat(378.5)

        colorPalleteImageView.frame.size.width = 348
        colorPalleteImageView.frame.size.height = cHeight

        let plusImg = UIImage(named: "plus")
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: plusImg)
        imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: cHeight-22, width: 22, height: 22)
        colorPalleteImageView.addSubview(imageView)

    }

}
```

and I got: (on iPad)

[image]

Comment: Happy to see this, But the thing is, I created the colorImageView in xib and the plusIconImageView by programmatically, could you please try like that and let me know how it is coming for you? I think If I create both the images programmatically then it will work fine.